# How to flash the desktop when I'm receiving an email?

Tags: c#, winapi, screen, gdi

I'm developing a email client and I want the screen to flash briefly when I receive a mail. I searched anywhere I could in .NET documentation, but the only way I found to achieve it was to use DirectX functions which is of course impossible : I don't want my users to install DirectX only for a mail client :)

Is there a way to do this only with GDI ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fortunately, there is no way for an application to do this sort of annoying thing. Your program should use the [notification area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511448.aspx) for notifying users of events and/or status changes.

Check out the [WPF Notification Area](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/48cb1a08-7bb3-401c-b09b-12e8b897cabf) example to see how you can use this in a WPF application...

Comment: Equally the application could use the show alert ability of Windows to flash its task bar icon (avoid split focus). Use P/Invoke to call FlashWindowEx: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679347(VS.85).aspx

Comment: I agree with you VoidPointer, this is a really annoying thing. But it's my customer's wish... And customer is.. customer ;)
Thanks for your answers, I'll try your solution and Richard's too.

Answer (score 2):

There's a good reason functionality like this isn't built into Windows.  Displaying large flashing rectangles is prone to induce seizures in people that suffer from [photosensitive epilepsy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosensitive_epilepsy).

Don't do this.

Comment: I totally agree with you... But as I said above, that's what my customer want. I told him about photosensitive epilepsy and he doesn't care... No comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what kind of flash effect you're looking for, but you could achive this by briefly showing a full-screen semi-transparent form -- see the `Opacity` property.